# JS .animate() not working in Firefox/IE

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, gecko

So I'm trying to animate a div but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. The following code works just fine on the latest Safari and Chrome but not on Internet Explorer and Firefox.
On Firefox, the error being `el.animate is not a function`
Any suggestions/solutions?

```js
var slowMo = false;
var dur = slowMo ? 5000 : 500;

function $(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

var players = {};

var hue = 0;

function addTouch(e) {
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.classList.add('ripple');
  var color = 'hsl(' + (hue += 70) + ',100%,50%)';
  el.style.background = color;
  var trans = 'translate(' + e.pageX + 'px,' + e.pageY + 'px) '
  console.log(trans);
  var player = el.animate([{
    opacity: 0.5,
    transform: trans + "scale(0) "
  }, {
    opacity: 1.0,
    transform: trans + "scale(2) "
  }], {

    duration: dur

  });
  player.playbackRate = 0.1;
  players[e.identifier || 'mouse'] = player;

  document.body.appendChild(el);
  player.onfinish = function() {
    if (!document.querySelector('.ripple ~ .pad')) each(document.getElementsByClassName('pad'), function(e) {
      e.remove();
    });
    el.classList.remove('ripple');
    el.classList.add('pad');

  }
}

function dropTouch(e) {
  players[e.identifier || 'mouse'].playbackRate = 1;
}

function each(l, fn) {
  for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
    fn(l[i]);
  }
}
document.body.onmousedown = addTouch;
document.body.onmouseup = dropTouch;

document.body.ontouchstart = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  each(e.changedTouches, addTouch);
};
document.body.ontouchend = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  each(e.changedTouches, dropTouch);
};

var el = document.body;

function prevent(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

el.addEventListener("touchstart", prevent, false);
el.addEventListener("touchend", prevent, false);
el.addEventListener("touchcancel", prevent, false);
el.addEventListener("touchleave", prevent, false);
el.addEventListener("touchmove", prevent, false);




function fakeTouch() {
  var touch = {
    pageX: Math.random() * innerWidth,
    pageY: Math.random() * innerHeight,
    identifier: 'fake_' + Math.random() + '__fake'
  }
  addTouch(touch);
  var length = Math.random() * 1000 + 500;
  setTimeout(function() {
    dropTouch(touch);
  }, length)
  setTimeout(function() {
    fakeTouch();
  }, length - 100)

}
if (location.pathname.match(/fullcpgrid/i)) fakeTouch(); //demo in grid
```

```css
.ripple {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vmax;
  height: 100vmax;
  top: -50vmax;
  left: -50vmax;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.pad {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="pad"></div>
```

[Code thanks to Kyle](http://codepen.io/KyleDavidE/pen/ByQpyG)

Comment: `.animate()` is not a DOM method, `Animation` is not supported in ie, though supported in firefox 40+.

Comment: @guest271314 Any way I can configure it work in IE? Also, I'm testing on FF 44.0.2

Comment: IE doesn't support it at all, so you can't configure it to work in IE, you can use a library like jQuery to help create cross browser animations.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Animation#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @guest271314 Go through a list of elements of and perform a function for each of them

Comment: Where is `each()` defined in `js` at Question ?

Comment: @guest271314 Line 43

Comment: @NajmSheikh Ahh, did not notice the function

Comment: @guest271314 No worries haha. I should've cleaned the code up a bit more.

Comment: @NajmSheikh You could also look into `requestAnimationFrame`

Answer (score 0):

So I took a different approach to achieve the same result. I think this one is a lot more straightforward and works in all browsers.

https://jsfiddle.net/cbrmuxcq/1/

Though there is a slight issue and I'm not sure what causes it. If I don't wait (by using `setTimeout()`), the transition doesn't happen but by setting a timeout it does. If anyone can spot the issue, I'll fix the fiddle and update my answer accordingly.